# Error while performing Test train and validation split on H2O frame

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I am trying to perform a test, train and validation split. But I am getting the following error.

Code:

```
hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df_train_transformed)
hf.types
```

Output:

```
{'Country': 'enum',
 'CustomerID': 'enum',
 'DayOfWeek': 'enum',
 'Description': 'enum',
 'Quantity': 'real',
 'StockCode': 'enum',
 'UnitPrice': 'real',
 'WeekOfYear': 'enum'}
```

Test, Train Validation Split:

```
train, valid, test = hf.split_frame(ratios=[0.7, 0.15], seed=42)
```

Error:

> H2OResponseError: Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Error: Requires same count of rows in the number-list (284780) as in the source (122049)
> Request: POST /99/Rapids
> data: {'ast': "(tmp= py_51_sid_9de8 (rows (tmp= py_49_sid_9de8 (:= (tmp= py_48_sid_9de8 (:= (tmp= py_47_sid_9de8 (:= (tmp= py_46_sid_9de8 (:= (tmp= py_45_sid_9de8 (:= (tmp= py_44_sid_9de8 (:= Key_Frame__upload_b047d82e4093133936d7ae7cf1534bc5.hex (as.factor (cols_py Key_Frame__upload_891dc3c514d9a9b9bcbcb14cef0c43b6.hex 'CustomerID')) 4 [])) (as.factor (cols_py py_44_sid_9de8 'Country')) 5 [])) (as.factor (cols_py py_45_sid_9de8 'Description')) 1 [])) (as.factor (cols_py py_46_sid_9de8 'DayOfWeek')) 7 [])) (as.factor (cols_py py_47_sid_9de8 'WeekOfYear')) 6 [])) (as.factor (cols_py py_48_sid_9de8 'StockCode')) 0 [])) (<= (tmp= py_50_sid_9de8 (h2o.runif py_49_sid_9de8 42)) 0.7)))", 'session_id': '_sid_9de8'}

Comment: Can you look in ther server-side logs for the assiciated error message (and perhaps a stack trace)?